# Login doesn't go through with custom backend

Tags: django

I've tried to login using email instead of username, so I used a custom backend. The form does check if the email is right and the password matches (as in, I get errors if the form is not filled right), however it doesn't log the user in, whereas using the username (after removing
 AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS), I can login just fine.

So I think it comes from the backend however it seems like it working, I used prints and it does return a user.
Here is my backends.py, stored in the file 'users'

```
from .models import User
class EmailBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=username)
        except User.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            return None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        if getattr(user, 'is_active') and user.check_password(password):
            #print('reached')
            return user
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try: 
            User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

And here is how I call it

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'users.backends.EmailBackend',
)
```

I'm actually puzzled as to why it doesn't log the user in if the role of the backend is just to return a user. So if someone could explain me what I did wrong and what is the actual purpose of the backend.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return is missing from get_user.

```
def get_user(self, user_id):
    try: 
        # HERE
        return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```